# $ \int_a^b (cf)(x)dx=c\int_a^b f(x)dx$ - $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I have to prove that $$ \int_a^b (cf)(x)dx=c\int_a^b f(x)dx)$$

This is my approach:

If $c=0$ it's trivial.

Let $\varepsilon>0$, $c\neq0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that: ($S(f,P)$ denotes Riemman's sum),

$$||P||<\delta\implies| S(f,P)-\int_a^bf(x)dx|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}$$

Observation: $$S(c.f,P,\{x_i\})=\sum_{i=1}^n(cf)(x_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})=c\sum_{i=1}^nf(x_i)(t_i-t_{i-1})=c\cdot S(f,P,\{x_i\})$$

Then, $$| S(cf,P)-c\int_a^bf(x)dx|=|c\cdot S(f,P)-c\int_a^bf(x)dx|=|c||\displaystyle S(f,P)-\int_a^bf(x)dx|<\frac{\varepsilon}{|c|}|c|=\varepsilon$$

QED.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, add a "... forall $P$ with $\|P\| < \delta$ and the end.

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: Great, thank you very much!

Comment: Don't forget to add "solution-verification" tag when asking to validate a proof!